# Correct projection of error ellipsoid onto horizontal plane.

Tags: conic-sections, projection, ellipsoids

While solving some problem, I obtained the error ellipsoid as an uncertainty estimate of point location in 3-D space. In fact, error ellipsoid is given by standard error (SERR), azimuth, and dip of three orthogonal principal vectors that fully describes an ellipsoid. For example, we can think of a case where 3 vectors are $(SERR, AZ, DIP)=(2.04,\,173,\,17),\,(1.45,\,323,\,69),\,(0.71,\,80,\,9)$. Here, the unit of $SERR$ is in km and unit of $AZ$ and $DIP$ are both in degrees.

Actually, what I want to do is not plotting error ellipsoid in 3-D space but plotting projection of ellipsoid (i.e. error ellipse) onto horizontal (x-y) plane. To do this, I thought of the method of finding major axis in horizontal plane by calculating horizontal projection of each principal axes by multiplying $\cos(DIP)$ to each $SERR$ and choosing the one with maximum projection length as major axis and taking corresponding azimuth for projection. However, I also should determine the minor axis in horizontal plane but actually azimuths of principal axes are not exactly orthogonal in 3-D so I got confused about way to get correct minor axis in this way. Is there more appropriate way of projecting ellipsoid onto horizontal plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are the orthogonal principal vectors of the ellipsoid,
let $A$ be the matrix having vectors
$$
\pmatrix{\displaystyle{v_1\over|v_1|^2} 
&\displaystyle {v_2\over|v_2|^2}
&\displaystyle{v_3\over|v_3|^2}}
$$
as columns, and define $M=AA^T$.
Then the cartesian equation of the ellipsoid can be written as
$$
\tag1
\pmatrix{x & y & z}M\pmatrix{x\\ y\\ z}=1.
$$
The gradient $n=M\pmatrix{x\\ y\\ z}$ of the left hand side gives the direction of the normal: the points corresponding to the border of the projection on plane $xy$ (which is an ellipse) are those whose gradient has vanishing $z$ component, i.e. those on the plane described by $n_z=0$.

Rewrite the equation of that plane, expressing $z$ as a function of $x$, $y$ and plug the result into $(1)$: the resulting equation is that of the desired projection.

Example.

Suppose $v_1=(1,1,2)$, $v_2=(2,0,1)$, $v_3=(-1,5,-2)$.
Then we get:
$$
m=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{17}{90} & \frac{1}{45} & -\frac{1}{45} \\
 \frac{1}{45} & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{2}{45} \\
 -\frac{1}{45} & \frac{2}{45} & \frac{7}{45} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and the equation of the ellipsoid is
$$
\tag2
\frac{1}{90} \left(17 x^2+4 x (y-z)+5 y^2+8 y z+14 z^2\right)=1.
$$
We also get
$$
n=\pmatrix{\frac{17 x}{90}+\frac{y}{45}-\frac{z}{45}\\
\frac{x}{45}+\frac{y}{18}+\frac{2z}{45}\\
-\frac{x}{45}+\frac{2 y}{45}+\frac{7 z}{45}}
$$
and from
$\displaystyle 
n_z=-\frac{x}{45}+\frac{2 y}{45}+\frac{7 z}{45}=0$
we obtain
$$
z={1\over7}(x-2y).
$$
Plugging this into $(2)$ we finally obtain the equation of the projection:
$$
13x^2+4xy+3y^2=70.
$$